# Save data from REST POST call in Node

Tags: node.js, rest, promise

I want to be able to save different API calls that I do into functions, so that I can call these functions to get the data I need. Here is the code I had in Node.js:

```
"use strict";

var rp = require('request-promise');

function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'some_uri',
        body: {
           "username": "username",
           "password": "password"
        },
        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
    };
    rp(options)
        .then(function (parsedBody) {
             resolve(parsedBody.accessToken);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
             reject(err);
        });
     }
)}
```

Is there any way for me to basically save the data from this function to a variable? Instead of returning a promise, can I return something else and be able to do

```
var token = getAccessToken();

console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

request-promise library returns promise only, its not at all required to wrap `rp` with Promise inside the `getAccessToken()` function.

In the following snippet, perform all your executions in `init()` method. It is async function. It waits for the `getAccessToken()` execution and assign the value to variable token

```
"use strict";

var rp = require('request-promise');

function getAccessToken() {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'some_uri',
        body: {
           "username": "username",
           "password": "password"
        },
        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
    };
    return rp(options);
)

async function init() {
    try {
        var tokenInfo = await getAccessToken();
        console.log(tokenInfo);
    } catch (e) {
        // Console err
    }
}

init();
```

Note: Not tested code